# Counting sort not sorting correctly

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have written this counting sort algorithm, but am not sure why it isn't working... Could anyone check and give me a few pointers on what to fix? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[10] = {1434, 1415, 1217, 4218, 3618, 176, 1021, 3785, 1891, 1522};

    int C[4219];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4219; ++i) {
        C[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        C[arr[j]] = C[arr[j]] + 1;
    }

    for (int k = 10; k > 0; --k) {
        C[k] = C[k] + C[k + 1];
    }

    int B[10];
    for (int l = 0; l < 10; ++l) {
        B[C[arr[l]] - 1] = arr[l];
        C[arr[l]] = C[arr[l]] - 1;
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < 10; ++m) {
        cout << B[m] << " ";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit code in your question when it invalidates posted answers. I rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the third loop. You iterate only through `10` elements of the array `C`.

Comment: doesn't fix it, even if I change the 10 to 4219

Comment: @icyfox why do you decrease the value of `k` in the third loop? do you want to sort in descending order?

Comment: @icyfox if you replace the loop with `for (int k = 1; k < 4219; k++) C[k] = C[k] + C[k-1];` it should work

Comment: holy... thanks! it does work now, guess I made a mistake in this loop

Answer (score 1):

You had created small mistake in the code.....

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int arr[10] = {1434, 1415, 1217, 4218, 3618, 176, 1021, 3785, 1891, 1522};

int C[4219];
for (int i = 0; i < 4219; ++i) {
    C[i] = 0;
}

for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
    C[arr[j]] = C[arr[j]] + 1;
}

for (int k = 1; k < 4219; ++k) {           // mistake
    C[k] = C[k] + C[k - 1];
}

int B[10];
for (int l = 9; l >=0; --l) {                         // suggestion 
    B[C[arr[l]] - 1] = arr[l];
    C[arr[l]] = C[arr[l]] - 1;
}

for (int m = 0; m < 10; ++m) {
    cout << B[m] << " ";
}

return 0;
}
```

Beside that I would like to give you one suggestion that in the loop traverse from right to left as it will maintain the stability of the sort..
Stability means suppose if array has two or more same element then in the stable sort,element which is before in unsorted array will occur first in sorted array.